# free-jqgrid: programmatically do a local multipleSearch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

after looking for hours and even days, I still could not find a satisfying solution to my problem:

all I want to do is to use the local search/filter options of jqgrid (currently using free-jqgrid 4.9.0) programmatically.

I want to do something like a local "multipleSearch" for example - without having to reload the data from the server.

what I have found and tried so far is this code:

```
var filters = { "groupOp": "AND", "rules": [{ "field": "my_field", "op": "eq", "data": "1234" }] };

//To filter:
jqGridFilter(filters , $('#my_grid'));
```

but it seems this only applies to old versions of jqgrid since I only get the error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: jqGridFilter is not defined"

**TL;DR:** I "just" want to do a local "multipleSearch" with (preferably) free-jqgrid 4.9.0 programmatically.

thanks for any help!

**UPDATE:**

after trying out the `postData` way Oleg mentioned in his comment my main problem was that i used a "groupOp" with only 1 rule:

```
postData = {
  filters : {"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"name","op":"cn","data":"anne"}]},
  search : true
}
```

when omitting the "groupOp" option it worked a couple of times. my code looked like this:

```
$("#grid").jqGrid("setGridParam", { 
    postData : {
        filters     :   {"rules":[{"field":"name","op":"cn","data":"anne"}]},
        search      :   true
        }
    }).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

after a couple of times reloading and trying different filters, the original code did not work anymore for some strange reason. I don't know what's wrong - either it's me or some strange bugs in free-jqgrid.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle of what you currently have? Include your current search/filters and some sample data. You can use [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alan0xd7/6ywe9rp5/) as a base if you wish, it is based on [this file](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/tests/fillingTest.htm) from free-jqgrid but without the tests.

Comment: I don't guarantee to have a solution for you, but having some working code to start with helps a lot.

Comment: @alan0xd7 thanks. to create a fiddle out of my jqgrid would be some hours of work for me. and I just wanna know a very basic thing: how can i do a "multipleSearch" programmatically? - the fiddle you showed takes forever to load for some reason. if you cancel the loading, I can see the javascript code. but there is nothing like a programmatically done "multipleSearch" in there imho. I just need the code to perform the search, nothing else.

Comment: Have you looked at the [searchfilter](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/plugins/jquery.searchfilter.js) plugin? It seems to do what you want.

Comment: I am in vocation this week. I can try to help you later if you will find no solution till the time. In general it seems you need just set filters property of postData parameter of jqGrid, set search parameter to true and trigger reloadGrid.

Comment: @Oleg thank you. I solved my problem with a serverside-workaround for now (which is very slow of course). I will try to reproduce the original problem at home with a simple grid where I can show you the whole code. (I also wonder if the problem is caused by side-effects)

Comment: You are welcome! search:true is **not** property of postData. It's parameter of jqGrid like postData or datatype.

Comment: @Oleg when i put `search:true` into the right position I get an alert box which says: 'TypeError: cannot read property "toString" of undefined'

Comment: You should post the code or better the demo which reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To apply filtering of data one need do the following

```
$("#grid").jqGrid("setGridParam", { 
    postData: {
        filters: JSON.stringify({
            groupOp: "AND",
            rules: [
                { field: "name", op: "cn", data: "anne" }
            ]
        })
    },
    search: true
}).trigger("reloadGrid", { page: 1 });
```

Where `"name"` is the name of the column in `colModel` where one want to set filter.

Comment: thank you oleg! it turned out that my main problems have been: 1) putting `search : true` in the wrong spot. 2) misformatting issues in my `filters` JSON (filters are very poorly documented imho). and i have to point out that i did not need to use `JSON.stringify()` in my solution.